# Examples for "serverless" Java service for AWS Lambda

Tags: java, architecture, domain-driven-design, aws

Doesn anybody have practical experience with implementing a (micro)service based on AWS Lambda?

My team is currently working on an MVP. We started with a monolith and that has worked very well. It's a new business domain and we still have to learn a lot about which [bounded contexts](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM7Yytr9TSAhWIJ8AKHc1bBpYQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmartinfowler.com%2Fbliki%2FBoundedContext.html&usg=AFQjCNGwnlC9zi4vWO-Cq_Fg8mxr3C_jYA) make sense and where to draw boundaries between them. Now we want to extract one of the contexts into its own service as a collection of AWS Lambda functions.

Our idea is to create one Java project with shared domain and data access code and multiple Lambda handlers. The idea is to create multiple independent functions based on the same Java project. (We want use an event-based pub/sub model for inter-service communication, so we don't see a need for API Gateway. We'd rather wire the functions up with DynamoDB streams or Kinesis directly.)

We are all convinced that this is worth a try, but we'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel. Does anybody have experience with such an approach and can share some insights, links, etc.? Has anybody tried the [Serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) framework with Java?

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: I do not agree with the comment above, its a good question for software engineering, serverless is something really new and there is not a guindance yet.

So ... I'm using AWS Lambdas with Kotlin, and I'm using the [serverless] (https://serverless.com/) framework. I do not have experience yet, I'm working on it right now.

I'm not using DDD (but i work with it) for it and created my project (it has a low level complexity) independently among the Handlers

Each "CRUD" operation on my REST Resource has its own Lambda Handler, "Service" (from hexagonal arch.) and its own repositoy.

Comment: Some common business logic would be great (a repository and agreggate for a resource, and not a repository for a lambda handler, like i did, *but* i did it because of performance considerations, but i don´t know with this considerations are really necessaries...

Comment: @EagleBeak, it was a good question. Have you found any examples regarding that? There is still few material available.